# when installing webRtc quickblox podfile for adding video calling feature the terminal displaying "dependency target not used in any target" error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

podfile content

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.2'
pod 'QuickBlox'

The dependency `Quickblox-WebRTC (~> 2.2)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `QuickBlox` is not used in any concrete target.

Comment: What version of cocoapods and what is your pod file contents

Comment: am using cocoapods 1.0.1 version

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding details in comments

Comment: do u have any solution for my question?@Wain

Comment: please don't re-add tags that i have removed, they were removed for a reason

Answer (score 0):

With CocoaPods 1.0.1 the pod file format has changed somewhat, so you need to explicitly define the targets that the pods apply to:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'XXX' do
    pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.2'
    pod 'QuickBlox'
end
```

Comment: Thanks wain..its generating pods project ..another thing did u work in video call feature ??

Comment: please ask a different question for any other issues